# MVC WebApi. Want to get format of HttpResponseMessage according to current formatter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Below is my Get method of MVC Web Api RC.

```
public Employee Get(int id)
{
     Employee emp= null;

     //try getting the Employee with given id, if not found, gracefully return error message with notfound status
     if (!_repository.TryGet(id, out emp))
         throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
         {
             Content = new StringContent("Sorry! no Employee found with id " + id),
             ReasonPhrase = "Error"
         });

      return emp;
}
```

Here problem is that whenever an error is thrown "Sorry! no Employee found with id ", is just in a plane text format. However i wanted to set the format as per my current formatter. Like by default i have set XML formatter in my global.asax. So the error should be displayed in XML format. Something like :

```
<error>
  <error>Sorry! no Employee found with id </error>
</error>
```

similarly for Json formatter. It should be :

```
[{"errror","Sorry! no Employee found with id"}]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a `StringContent`. This means that the contents will be returned as-is and it is up to you to format it.

Personally I would define a model:

```
public class Error
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
if (!_repository.TryGet(id, out emp))
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
        new Error { Message = "Sorry! no Employee found with id " + id }
    );
    throw new HttpResponseException(response);
}
```

A XML Accept enabled client would then see:

```
<Error xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AppName.Models">
    <Message>Sorry! no Employee found with id 78</Message>
</Error>
```

and a JSON Accept enabled client would see:

```
{"Message":"Sorry! no Employee found with id 78"}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *stuck*? What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i had pressed enter key, that posted my incomplete message. Actually i wanted to ask that i am stuck at OnActionExecuting event of a filter (ActionFilterAttribute). public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context) { context.Response = ? (how to send out error messsge from here, in the same way we did it from Get method)}

Comment: I got a solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189161/mvc4-web-api-how-to-return-error-message-from-catch-block-right-now-empty-is-r