# How to return error message from Catch block. Right now empty is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My sample code of ApiKey validation is given below (I am using MVC4 web api RC):

```
public class ApiKeyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        //read api key from query string
        string querystring = context.Request.RequestUri.Query;
        string apikey = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring).Get("apikey");

        //if no api key supplied, send out validation message
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apikey))
        {                
            var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new Error { Message = "You can't use the API without the key." });
            throw new HttpResponseException(response);
        }
        else
        {          
             try
            {
                GetUser(decodedString); //error occurred here
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new Error { Message = "User with api key is not valid" });
                throw new HttpResponseException(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here problem is with Catch block statement. I Just wanted to send custom error message to user. But nothing is sent. It displays a blank screen

However, the statement below is working well and sends out the validation error message correctly:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apikey))
{                
    var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new Error { Message = "You can't use the API without the key." });
    throw new HttpResponseException(response);
}
```

Is there anything that i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having the same issue in the exact same scenario. However, in this scenario, you need to return some content in your response to be shown and not really throw the exception. So based on this, I would change your code to the following:

```
 catch (Exception)
 {
    var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(httpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    response.Content = new StringContent("User with api key is not valid");
    context.Response = response;
 }
```

So with this change you are now returning your response, with content that will displayed in place of the blank screen.

Comment: Thanks Paige Cook, I can get the StringContent now "User with api key is not valid" instead of blank screen :-). But another concern here is that instead of plain text, i wanted to get the result in  current formatter's format like in xml or json. For this i need to assign response.Content = new Error { Message = "You can't use the API without the key." }. This code is not working and is a compile error. How to write the code line here ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to do that. There could be a way to determine the MediaType of the request and format the message to the same MediaType.

Comment: Yes, i am looking for it. If got something i will post here.

Comment: Hi Paige, i got it and posted here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225806/mvc-web-api-rc-sending-formatted-error-message-to-client-from-catch-block/11226955#11226955

Comment: I'd recommend `CreateErrorResponse()` instead.