# Sending formatted error message to client from catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i am using the following code to send out error message to client from a filter(ActionFilterAttribute).

```
catch (Exception)
 {
    var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(httpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    response.Content = new StringContent("User with api key is not valid");
    context.Response = response;
 }
```

But problem is that it sends out in plain text only. I wanted to send it as format of current formatter. Like in form of json or xml.

Here i know that this is because i am using StringContent(). But how can we write using custom Error object?
like, the following is not working either:

```
response.Content = new Error({Message = "User with api key is not valid"});
```

How do we write code for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ya, i found the correct syntax of writing. We can write like:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
                        new Error { Message = "User with api key is not valid"});
    context.Response = response; 
}
```